# How to obtain a unique labeling for the vertices of the graph defined below?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, linear-programming

Let $\left( V,E \right)$ be a simple, undirected graph without loops. Consider an edge $e=\left\{ {v}',{v}'' \right\}$ and a set $L\left( v \right)$ containing the possible labels of $v\in V$, for which $L\left( {{v}'} \right)\cap L\left( {{v}''} \right)=\varnothing $. Define a „weight” function ${{w}_{e}}:L\left( {{v}'} \right)\times L\left( {{v}''} \right)\to {{\mathbb{Z}}_{\ge 0}}$ over the edge   and let $\Lambda :V\to {{\cup }_{v\in V}}L\left( v \right)$ be a function with $\Lambda \left( v \right)\in L\left( v \right)$ for any $v\in V$. I would like to get a ${{\Lambda }^{*}}:V\to {{\cup }_{v\in V}}L\left( v \right)$ function such that
$${{\Lambda }^{*}}=\underset{\Lambda }{\mathop{\arg \min }}\,\sum\limits_{\left\{ {v}',{v}'' \right\}\in E}{{{w}_{e}}\left( \Lambda \left( {{v}'} \right),\Lambda \left( {{v}''} \right) \right)}$$
Is there any efficient algorithm to obtain this function? Could it be reduced to a well-known algorithm?

Comment: where you did you get this theory from?

Comment: I would like to assign a high-resolution FT-IR spectra (spectroscopy). I have several edges. For each edge I have a number of potential "vertex label" pairs, with such integers which are the measures of goodness of the label pairs. I would like to get an optimal assignment for the vertices.